# In Django 1.9, what's the convention for using JSONField (native postgres jsonb)?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, jsonb

Django [highly suggests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#null) **not** to use `null=True` for CharField and TextField string-based fields in order not to have two possible values for "no data" (assuming you're allowing empty strings with `blank=True`).  This makes total sense to me and I do this in all my projects.

Django 1.9 introduces [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField), which uses the underlying Postgres `jsonb` data type.  Does the suggestion above carry over to JSONField (i.e. `blank=True` should be used instead of `null=True`)?  Or, should `null=True` be used instead?  Or, should `default=dict` be used instead?  Or, ..?  Why?

In other words, what is the convention for the new native JSONField, when you want to allow only one "no data" value?  Please support your answer because I did a lot of research and couldn't find anything official.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: after reading the docs, I would bet null=True is best, as JSONField should be a valid object, and typically "empty" objects you use null assignments to indicate that. just my 2c.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The convention implied from the Django code seems to be to **store null JSON values as NULL** as opposed to as an empty string (as is the convention for the `CharField`). I say this because of the following:

The `empty_strings_allowed` is inherited from `Field` in `CharField`, and is set to `True`:

[django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L96](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L96)

```
class Field(RegisterLookupMixin):
    """Base class for all field types"""

    # Designates whether empty strings fundamentally are allowed at the
    # database level.
    empty_strings_allowed = True
    ...
```

`JSONField`, however, overrides it with `False`:

[django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb.py#L13](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb.py#L13)

```
class JSONField(Field):
    empty_strings_allowed = False
    ...
```

This causes `CharField`'s to default to `""` and `JSONField`'s to `None` when you instantiate a model without explicitly passing the values for these fields.

[django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L791](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L791)

```
def get_default(self):
    """
    Returns the default value for this field.
    """
    if self.has_default():
        if callable(self.default):
            return self.default()
        return self.default
    if (not self.empty_strings_allowed or (self.null and
               not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls)):
        return None
    return ""
```

Therefore, if you want to make a `JSONField` optional, you have to use:

```
json_field = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

If you use only `blank=True`, as you would for `CharField`, you'll get an `IntegrityError` when trying to run `MyModel.objects.create(...)` without passing a `json_field` argument explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add that you should avoid setting default values on JSONField. I just made a schoolboy error by setting it to `{}`. The result is that new objects will receive the last object's value if it was not explicitly set. Its a Python behaviour inherent in the JSONField, which I forgot to consider.

Comment: You don't need to avoid a default. This problem happened because you provided a mutable object as a default. You should provide the callable `dict` instead of `{}`. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField): "If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as dict (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a dict (such as a function). Incorrectly using default={} creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of JSONField."