# How to store None as JSON 'null' rather than SQL NULL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, null, jsonb

I'm using [contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) to store some JSON data with Django 1.11.

Contrary to the convention described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126751/754254), I'd like to store `None` as JSON. However, Django by default tries to store `None` as SQL `NULL`, and errors if I set the field to `null=False`.

Is there any way to get Django to store `None` as `'none'::jsonb`?

Comment: have you tried replacing all `None`s with the string `null`.

Comment: Yep -- I get `'"null"'::jsonb` in the DB then

Comment: `import json` and then `json.dumps(None)` would might help.

Comment: @D.S That's the same suggestion as the previous comment